# How to load markers on the Google maps dynamically and draw a route between them?

Tags: google-maps

I need to make a page with a google map in it. It will have a fix point inside (the company's office).

Outside of map,I will have a drop down. 
When user selects an option from the list, i need to show on map the selected option and draw a line (route) to connect the two points.

So far i am able to have a fixed point on map with custom icon, but i cannot find a way to add a second point dynamically, and draw a route between the two points.

Is this possible? I have not found any tutorials on this and i was wondering if anyone can point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With some modifications, this example should get you started:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Directions Simple</title>
<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var directionDisplay;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var map;

  function initialize() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom:7,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: chicago
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  }

  function calcRoute() {
    var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
    var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
    var request = {
        origin:start, 
        destination:end,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div>
<b>Start: </b>
<select id="start" onchange="calcRoute();">
  <option value="chicago, il">Chicago</option>
  <option value="st louis, mo">St Louis</option>
  <option value="joplin, mo">Joplin, MO</option>
  <option value="oklahoma city, ok">Oklahoma City</option>
  <option value="amarillo, tx">Amarillo</option>
  <option value="gallup, nm">Gallup, NM</option>
  <option value="flagstaff, az">Flagstaff, AZ</option>
  <option value="winona, az">Winona</option>
  <option value="kingman, az">Kingman</option>
  <option value="barstow, ca">Barstow</option>
  <option value="san bernardino, ca">San Bernardino</option>
  <option value="los angeles, ca">Los Angeles</option>
</select>
<b>End: </b>
<select id="end" onchange="calcRoute();">
  <option value="chicago, il">Chicago</option>
  <option value="st louis, mo">St Louis</option>
  <option value="joplin, mo">Joplin, MO</option>
  <option value="oklahoma city, ok">Oklahoma City</option>
  <option value="amarillo, tx">Amarillo</option>
  <option value="gallup, nm">Gallup, NM</option>
  <option value="flagstaff, az">Flagstaff, AZ</option>
  <option value="winona, az">Winona</option>
  <option value="kingman, az">Kingman</option>
  <option value="barstow, ca">Barstow</option>
  <option value="san bernardino, ca">San Bernardino</option>
  <option value="los angeles, ca">Los Angeles</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id="map_canvas" style="top:30px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Code from: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple.html

Please refer to the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html) if you wish to read up on `MapOptions` and `MapTypeId`, for instance, if you wish to do other customisations to your map.

Comment: wow... perfect. Many thanks for this code. This will put me on the right track of what i want to accomplish. Again, many thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you could also do, using stealthyninja's code, is in the calcRoute function, add a marker to the map at the appropriate end point.  And instead of place names, you could also use lat/lng coordinates (which might give you better results if the drop-off points have to be more exact).